# You have requested a non-existent service ""

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have the error `You have requested a non-existent service "isi_isi_manager"` But this service is registed.

How can it be possible?

**MyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    isi_isi_manager:
        class: SMFR\IsiBundle\Entity\IsiManager
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
```

**ISIExtension**

```
 public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
 {
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('config.yml');
}
```

Comment: Make sure your bundle is registered (app/AppKerner.php) and that you added a DI Extension that loads your service configuration from your bundle.

Comment: Stick a die in to your load method.  I'm guessing you have an extension naming issue.

Comment: check namespace in SMFR\IsiBundle\Entity\IsiManager if it matches. Also try clearing cache: `rm -rf cache/*`

Comment: Just for the record, why dont you stick with the symfony2 best pratices, and keep the services definition in a file named "services" which is loaded by default?

Comment: Solved the problem. The fact was that ubuntu looks searched file IsiExtension about not ISIExtension. Windows would not care.

Comment: should still stick to best practices